# What are the tools available in JPA for storing before and after data for audit purposes

Tags: oracle, rest, jpa, spring-boot, jpa-2.0

I'm working on SpringBoot--> Rest --> JPA -->Oracle Db. Now while sending a Put request, need to capture the before and after data of a particular column in a table to be stored and saved in a separate table again as an entity.

```
public EmployeeEntity update(int EmployeeID , EmployeeEntity employeeEntity)
{
 em = emf.createEntityManager();
 em.getTransaction().begin();
 em.merge(employeeEntity);
 em.getTransaction().commit();
 em.close();
}
```

Now if a employee's salary column is being updated or any other column in employee entity is being changed, it has to be captured as before salary and after salary and to be recorded into an separate audit table. Generally, for this a trigger with a stored procedure would be my idea, but since it being an entity any other good options available in JPA. Please do suggest any ideas.

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://struberg.wordpress.com/2010/07/31/howto-changelog-with-jpa/) can help you. In a very simplified way, you add an annotation on fields you want to track. In EntityListeners, you scan all annotated field and check if the value has changed. Otherwise, I see you're using Spring, does [this link](http://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa) help?

Comment: @ASE Thanks for the insights , i will go through them and give a try .